# DataGrid using SQLDataAdapter while updating getting error in vb.net winforms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have populated a DataGridView from the two tables.i am working on windows forms

In page load event I have this code:

```
Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter
Dim bSource As BindingSource
Dim dt1 As DataTable

     Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=SUPPORT2\SUPPORT2;Initial Catalog=Registry;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;password=solutions") 'SET THE CONNECTION STRING
            con.Open()

            Dim cd As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(adapter)
            adapter = New SqlDataAdapter("select c.CompanyName,d.dtName,d.dtPhone,d.dtEmail  from CompanyMaster_tbl c join  DepartmentMaster_tbl d on c.Cid=d.cId", con)
            dt1 = New DataTable
            bSource = New BindingSource
            adapter.Fill(dt1)
            bSource.DataSource = dt1
            gv.DataSource = bSource
        End Sub
```

in update button click i given code like this:

```
 Private Sub btnupdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnupdate.Click
    gv.EndEdit()
    bSource.EndEdit()
    adapter.Update(dt1)
End Sub
```

Whenever I edit something in the dataGridView and click update button i am getting error in this line **adapter.Update(dt1)** :Error:
Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection
>   with modified rows.

The error is correct, you need to provide an `UpdateCommand`, otherwise the dataadapter does not know how to update a record.

```
adapter.UpdateCommand = New SqlCommand("UPDATE CompanyMaster_tbl SET CompanyName = @CompanyName, dtName = @dtName, dtPhone = @dtPhone, dtEmail = @dtEmail WHERE Cid = @Cid", con)
```

You should use parameters to prevent sql-injection:

```
adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cid", cid)
adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyName", CompanyName)
adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtPhone", dtPhone)
adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtEmail", dtEmail)
```

Comment: sir..in this line :adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cid", cid) instead of cid i have to write corresponding data grid view column right?

Comment: That's the variable that you could provide manually.  You could use the  [`Current`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.current(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the `BindingSource`  to access the values.

Comment: sorry for asking this: how to use current property of BindingSource to access the values

Comment: @user3106114: try `dim rv =  DirectCast(bSource.Current, DataRowView) Dim companyName = rv.Row.Field(String)("CompanyName")` and so on in `btnupdate_Click`.

Comment: sir,the same time i want to update more than one column,,so this things i have to write in for loop?

Comment: @user3106114: as shown above you only have to provide all parameters in your update-sql. If you actually mean _rows_ instead of _columns_, have a look at this tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33y2221y(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: sir in this line adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cid", cid) getting error:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @user3106114: _what_ is `null`, the `UpdateCommand`? Then you have not used my code to initialize it: `adapter.UpdateCommand = New SqlCommand.....`